# How do I execute Python in Javascript without using Node.js? Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, python, executable

I have a Python script which I so far have been executing with PHP using `shell_exec()` which *outputs text to the HTML page*. Problem is, PHP is too slow and has to reload every single time I want a part of the page to be updated, so I thought about using Javascript, which is faster than PHP.

Since I don't want to rewrite my entire Python code into Javascript, is there a way to execute my Python without using Node.js? I am a complete newbie to Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What, exactly, does your Python script do?  I think you might be falling victim to the XY problem here.  If you need speed and you can implement your Python code in Javascript, then I don't think I can recommend anything less than rewriting your code.

Another option you might have is to execute your python script once per session and have it take an input (via REST or something) and return its output like that, but that honestly might be more work depending on your script.

Comment: My Python script is a text adventure game, which when run restores the game session, which is stored in a `pickle` file, and ask for user input (which is currently sent to Python using the `sys` module). I've decided to just use node.js since it is server side and can protect my code.

Comment: Another potential fix for you then: If your server code is very simple you can rewrite that instead in a Python framework like flask and then call it natively.  You definitely don't want to be unpickling state every time you need to update the webpage though, that will be very slow no matter what you do.  At worst keep your state in a JSON string and pass it in as an argument to your script.

Answer (score 1):

PHP isn't slow here, PHP itself can be very, very fast. What's slow is having to instantiate a shell and execute a child-process for every request. You'll see the same slowdown trying this pattern with any other language as well, unless you do something to cache the script's output and refresh that cache asynchronously.

You may also be confusing the role of JavaScript. Your server can run Python, PHP or JavaScript (JS would use the node.js runtime) and more. Anything server-side can call any other thing server-side. JavaScript can also run on the client-side in a visitor's browser.

JavaScript on the client-side doesn't have access to anything server-side unless you create an endpoint. Client-side JavaScript is really not much more capable than a user with a mouse and keyboard. The endpoint you'd create would trigger exactly the same slowdown you described above, except with more complexity.

Comment: So there is no other way to do this besides Javascript?